# jq - Add field to child, print parent

Tags: json, bash, pipe, immutability, jq

Problem: from a json file, read it up from disk and add a field to a child object and print it back to disk.

File:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "script": "index.js",
  "instances": "1",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 3000
  },
  "env_production": {
    "PORT": 3000
  }
}
```

So i've managed to pipe it and add the field:

```
cat pm2.json | jq --arg key val '. as $parent | .env_production + {"abc": "123"}'
```

Which returns the child object with the field added. However, I need to update the file on disk. So I also need to print the whole object (the parent).

I can do that by printing it the `$parent` variable. But I cannot get it to work since it is immutable.

```
cat pm2.json | jq --arg key val '. as $parent | .env_production + {"abc": "123"}| $parent'
```

Question: how can I do this so that the `$parent` variable have the new added field, so that I can pipe it back to the original file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tool to use here is an updating addition operator, `+=`

```
< pm2.json jq '.env_production += {"abc": "123"}'
```

will output

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "script": "index.js",
  "instances": "1",
  "env": {
    "PORT": 3000
  },
  "env_production": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "abc": "123"
  }
}
```

It works out to something similar to

```
. + {"env_production": (.env_production + {"abc":"123"})}
```

except of course it's far simpler :)

Comment: Or simply `.env_production += {"abc": "123"}`.

Comment: @hobbs - Could you update your answer to use `+=` so we can upvote it?

Answer (score 2):

What about using `sponge` along with `jq` like this:

```
jq '.env_production.abc = "123"' pm2.json | sponge pm2.json
```

The above command will append `abc: "123"` to `env_production` key and the output (the full json object) will be passed to `sponge` in order to update the file

> `sponge` is a part of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package

`sponge` has an advantage over shell redirection according to it's description in man pages:

> sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file. Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening the output file. This allows constricting pipelines that read from and write to the same file.